# PHP imap_search with current date

Tags: php, date, imap

I have the wierdest problem when using imap_search. If I call imap_search on a folder without any criterias, it returns all messages in the folder as expected. But lets say I use a date criteria (ON, SINCE or BEFORE), it refuses to return any messages from the current date.

So for example if I do:

```
imap_search($mbox, 'ON "'.$yesterday.'"');
```

It works just fine, but if I do:

```
imap_search($mbox, 'ON "'.$today.'"');
```

Nothing is returned. Anyone knows what is going on?

**UPDATE:**

When I look here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501 I can make out:

```
ON <date> 
Messages whose internal date (disregarding time and
timezone) is within the specified date.
```

And:

```
Clarify that date searches disregard the time and timezone of the
INTERNALDATE or Date: header.  In other words, "ON 13-APR-2000" means
messages with an INTERNALDATE text which starts with "13-APR-2000",
even if timezone differential from the local timezone is sufficient to
move that INTERNALDATE into the previous or next day.
```

This makes me also rule out that the problem has something to do with the timezone.

Comment: And what do $yesterday and $today look like?

Comment: "23-Nov-2016" and "24-Nov-2016" respectively. I've tried many different date formats, but no difference. And since it works perfectly with any other date except the current day, I've ruled out that date formatting is the problem.

Comment: Might be a bug in your IMAP server.  I came across one that did > rather than >= for SINCE.  Any idea what the server software is?

Comment: Also, the servers idea of INTERNALDATE may not be the time zone you expect.   Many operate in UTC, but not all.    This means it may not yet be 'today' for the server; although that would only explain ON or SINCE, not BEFORE.

Comment: Please refer to my updated question.

Comment: And have you checked that there ARE any messages with INTERNALDATEs with the date you requested?  Again, the RFC says timezone is ignored; this means no time zone processing occurs beyond what the server does when it assigns the INTERNALDATE.